# Derivative of real-valued function that takes a matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, chain-rule, hadamard-product

I want to compute the partial derivative of a real-valued function that takes matrices as argmuents.

The function has the form
$$F(x,y,z) = ||g(x) \odot (S \cdot y) - z||,$$
where $x, y, z, S \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ and g is a function $\mathbb{R}^{M \times N} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$.

So my question is: **What is the partial derivative of $\nabla_x F$?**

My try:
1.
I defined a new function
$$f(x,y,z) = ||x \odot (S \cdot y) - z||$$
so that
$$F(x,y,z) = f(g(x),y,z).$$

To compute the derivative of F, I tried to compute the derivative of f and g and then use the chain rule. But I am not sure if the chain rule holds in this case.

I computed the derivative of f:
$$    \nabla_x f(x,y,z) 
    = \left[ (  \cdot ) \odot S_i(y) \right]^* \left( x \odot S_i (y) - z_{ij} \right) 
   $$
$$
    =  \overline{S_i(y)} \odot  \left( x \odot S_i (y) - z_{ij} \right) \\
    $$
$$
    =S_i(\overline{y} \odot y) \odot  x -  S_i (\overline{y}) \odot z_{ij}\\
$$

Then with the chain rule
$$\nabla_{x_{rs}} F(x,y,z) = \nabla_x f(g(x),y,z) \cdot \nabla_{x_{rs}} g(x)$$
$$= \left( S_i(\overline{y} \odot y) \odot g(x) -  S_i (\overline{y}) \odot z \right) \cdot \nabla{x_{r,s}}g(x)$$
But here I am unsure if the chain rule holds for matrices and if yes, if it should be a matrix multiplication or the Hadamard product to multiply the derivative of g with the derivative of f.

2. Another idea would be to try to write the function $g(x) = M \cdot x$ for a matrix M and then compute the derivative of F directly. But I don't know if it is always possible to write a matrix-valued function, that takes a matrix as an argument as a matrix and how this would look in my case.
   The function $g(x)$ looks as follows:
   $$g(x) = \mathbb{F}^{-1}(\mathbb{F}(x) \odot Q), $$
   where $x, Q$ are matrices and $\mathbb{F}$ is the 2D discrete Fourier transform.
   The 2D Fourier transform looks as follows:
   $$\mathbb{F}: \mathbb{C}^{M \times N} \to \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}, \, X \mapsto Y$$
   with
   $$Y_{p,q} = \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp \left( -2 \pi i \left(\frac{mp}{M} + \frac{n q}{N}\right) \right) \cdot X_{m,n}, \, $$for
   $$ p=0,...,M-1, q = 0,...,N-1.$$

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\k{\otimes} \def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\BR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$I'll use a naming convention wherein Latin upper/lower case letters are matrices/vectors and Greek letters are scalars. This leads to renaming the problem variables $(F,x,y,z)\to(\varphi,X,Y,Z)$

Since the matrix $X$ has a **rectangular** shape, I'll assume that the function $g()$ is applied elementwise and that its derivative $g'()$  is known. The *differential* of such an elementwise matrix function is given by
$$\eqalign{
G = g(X),\quad
G' = g'(X) \qiq \c{dG = G'\h dX} \\
}$$
For typing convenience, introduce the matrix
$$\eqalign{
W &= G\h SY - Z \\
}$$
and the extremely versatile $\sf Frobenius\;Product$
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \LR{A\h B}_{ij}
   \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TB} \\
\LR{A\h B}:C &= A:\LR{B\h C}
 \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
}$$

Then square the objective function and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\def\P{\frac{\o}{\varphi}\:}
\varphi &= \frob{W} \\
\varphi^2 &= W:W \\
2\varphi\:d\varphi &= 2W:dW \\
d\varphi
 &= \P W:dW \\
 &= \P W:\LR{dG\h SY} \\
 &= \P\LR{W\h SY}:\c{dG} \\
 &= \P\LR{W\h SY}:\CLR{G'\h dX} \\
 &= \P\LR{G'\h W\h SY}:dX \\
\grad{\varphi}{X}
 &= \P\LR{G'\h W\h SY} \\
}$$
This result can be rewritten in terms of the *original* variables
$$\eqalign{
\grad Fx &= g'(x)\h\fracLR{g(x)\h Sy-z}F\h Sy \\
\\
}$$

### Update

For part 2, instead of an elementwise function, a DFT is used
$$\eqalign{
\def\F{{\mathbb F}}
\def\Fi{\F^{-1}}
G &= \Fi\bR{\,Q\h\F\LR{X}} \qiq
\c{dG = \Fi\bR{\,Q\h\F\LR{dX}}} \\
}$$
Substituting this new $\c{dG}$ into the differential yields
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\varphi}{X}
 &= \P\:\F\bR{\,Q\h\Fi\!\LR{W\h SY}} \\
}$$
The following DFT$-$Frobenius product rules are useful
$$\eqalign{
\F\!\LR{A}:B &= A:\F\!\LR{B} \\
\Fi\!\LR{A}:B &= A:\Fi\!\LR{B} \\
}$$

Comment: The function $g(x)$ does not work elementwise. I edited my question to show exactly how $g(x)$ looks.

Comment: thank you for the update!
By $\phi^{-1}$, do you mean $\frac{1}{\phi (X)}$?